# Ruby re-structuring data

Tags: ruby, arrays

I need to build an array of hashes that looks like this:

```
[
{:name=>"company", :value=>"Microsoft"}, 
{:name=>"type", :value=>"software"}, 
{:name=>"country", :value=>"US"}, 
{:name=>"valid", :value=>"yes"}
]
```

Rather than having to keep defining the name and value fields I've built a helper function that looks like this:

```
def build(attributes=[])
 list = []
 attributes.each {|k,v| list.push({:name=> "#{k}", :value=> "#{v}"})}
 list
end
```

I can then simply create my array like this:

```
attribs = { :company => 'Microsoft', :type => 'software', :country=> 'US', :valid=> 'yes'}
puts build(attribs).inspect

#[{:name=>"company", :value=>"Microsoft"}, {:name=>"type", :value=>"software"}, {:name=>"country", :value=>"US"}, {:name=>"valid", :value=>"yes"}]
```

This seems a litte inefficient and verbose for Ruby! Is there a cleaner or more efficient way to achieve this result?

Regards,

Carlskii

Comment: The structure looks very much like a representation of object state - are the values for :name always the same set, or do you need to cope with run-time variation?

Comment: No unfortunately I will need to handle runtime variations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that attributes has these kind of data:

```
attributes = [['company','Microsoft'],...]
```

Then to build hash from that:

```
attributes.map { |k,v| {:name => k, :value => v} }
#=> [{:name=>"company", :value=>"Microsoft"},...
```

Comment: Perfect! - I thought Ruby would provide a cleaner way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Ruby's [Hash.[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) method, which accepts an even number of arguments as key value pairs:

```
Hash['company', 'microsoft','type','software','country','us']
#=> {"company"=>"microsoft", "type"=>"software", "country"=>"us"}
```

This is often used in conjunction with Ruby's splat operator, which lets you pass an array as the method arguments.

```
attributes = ['company', 'microsoft','type','software','country','us']
Hash[*attributes]
#=> {"company"=>"microsoft", "type"=>"software", "country"=>"us"}
```